# Request permission notification Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions, notifications

I am trying to show a pop up for requesting notification permission. I have tried using `permission_handler` package but for notification and bluetooth, it will show no dialog. Is there any other way to show dialog to ask notification permission ?

Comment: I know it doesn't help but I'm having the same problem on Android 13. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @TomaszCz. I haven't found any solution yet for my case and still looking for it until now

Comment: I just try the solution from @Abdelrahman Tareq today and it works but for pop up notification we should do it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [notification_permission](https://pub.dev/packages/notification_permissions)

Comment: Hi I just try it today and so far it works fine, thank you very much @Abdelrahman Tareq for your help

Comment: You're welcome my friend

Answer (score 4):

Using permission_handler package, the following code will pop up a dialog requesting the user for notification permission:

```
Future<void> requestNotificationPermissions() async {
   final PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.request();
   if (status.isGranted) {
      // Notification permissions granted
   } else if (status.isDenied) {
      // Notification permissions denied
   } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      // Notification permissions permanently denied, open app settings
      await openAppSettings();
   }
}
```

You may call the function inside the main function or anywhere you see fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot after lib update to latest it working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue that it didn't show the pop up. Here is my solution:

- iOS:

In `Podfile`, I change value from `0` into `1` for permissions that I need to use. For ex:

```
...
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    # YOUR CUSTOM TARGET CODE HERE.
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',
   
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

- Android:

In `android -> app -> build.gradle`, I set `33` for `targetSdkVersion`. For ex:

```
...
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 // flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 33 // flutter.targetSdkVersion
        ...
    }

    ...
}
...
```

Hope this helps.